# Vim syntax highlighting for custom C types

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-c

I want to use syntax highlighting for custom C types. Based on my coding convention, types can occur in the following places:

```
typedef type1 type2;

(static | extern | register | volatile)? type ...;

(struct | enum | union) type ...;

func(type1 x, type2 x, ...);  // might be a harder case
```

It doesn't include all the situations, but can already cover probably more than 90% of the usage. It seems to me like just a simple pattern matching problem, but I was a bit frustrated playing with vim syntax script, and couldn't get what I need. For example, I don't know how to match part of the pattern without highlighting the rest. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: `\zs` and `\ze` are great for defining the start and end of the matching part of your pattern

Comment: @tommcdo It doesn't work for more than one group in the match. For example in the function signature case.

Comment: You just have to get more creative with your regular expression. Look for something like `type name` following *and* preceding any number of things like `type name`. Each parameter will match that same pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The way built-in types are declared is very simple. From `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/c.vim`:

```
syn keyword     cType           int long short char void
syn keyword     cType           signed unsigned float double
" [..etc..]
```

And then later on it sets a highlight group:

```
hi def link cType               Type
```

Adding to this syntax group is easy:

```
:syn keyword cType type1
```

Or is you want a different highlight group, use something like:

```
:syn keyword cTypeCustom type1
:hi def link cTypeCustom MyType
:hi MyType ctermfg=darkblue guifg=darkblue
```

---

The trick here is to let Vim know *which* custom types are yours. You *could* "regex it", but it seems to me that a far better and more robust solution would be to actually parse the C files and generate this information. It should be fairly easy to get this information with clang (this [tutorial](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html)) might help), you could then make this program write to `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The clang parser looks cool, but I already created my solution using regex on buffer enter, which is less 'correct' but seems easier to do. [This](https://github.com/lriuui/pocket_vim/blob/master/plugin/typezoo/typezoo.vim) is how I did it if you're interested.

Comment: @R.L You can [add that as an answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) so that people who find this question in the future (by a search or browser) can be helped by it ;-)