# Is it possible to use syn match dynamically

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight, syntax

I know that `syn match` can work with the regular expression to do some custom highlight settings.

I'm thinking if it can work dynamically.

For example, I'm doing a c++ project and I want to highlight all class/struct names. It's not hard to highlight these names while defining, I can do this with the help of `syn match` as below:

```
hi hiCppCustomClassName guifg=NONE guibg=NONE guisp=NONE gui=bold ctermfg=lightgreen ctermbg=NONE cterm=bold
syn match cppCustomClassName "\(^class\s*\)\@<=\w\+"
syn match cppCustomStructName "\(^struct\s*\)\@<=\w\+"
hi def link cppCustomClassName hiCppCustomClassName
hi def link cppCustomStructName hiCppCustomClassName
```

Basically, I match all words following the key word `class` and `struct` and highlight them.

However, if I define an object with some class, it won't be highlighted, which means that:

```
class Test{}; // Test is highlighted
Test t;       // Test it not highlighted
```

As there are many cases, such as `sizeof(Test)`, `(Test)obj`, the `syn match` with regular expression can not cover all of them, now I'm thinking if there is some dynamic mechanism so that I can find all class/struct names, put all of them into an array, loop this array and highlight all of them while coding.

BTW, I know there are some other ways to get a perfect highlight, for example, https://github.com/jeaye/color_coded, but these are kind of too heavy, for now I only want to get some simple, light way.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8931/10604